# Determine if an assistive technology is enabled in SwiftUI (like voice over)

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility

I wonder if there's a way to determine if any assistive technology like voice over is enabled in SwiftUI? I found out one answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669614) where I can specifically choose an assistive technology like `UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning`. But I wonder if there's a more "SwiftUI"-way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more SwiftUI-way to determine if any assistive technology is enabled is by using the `@Environment()` property wrapper and choose whatever assistive technology you liked.

#### Example:

```
// Determines if any assistive technology is active
@Environment(\.accessibilityEnabled) private var accessibilityEnabled

// Determines if voice over is enabled
@Environment(\.accessibilityVoiceOverEnabled) private var voiceOverEnabled

// Determines if reduce motion is enabled
@Environment(\.accessibilityReduceMotion) private var reduceMotionEnabled
```